# Dumping jsons and include date in filename

Tags: python, json, xml, parsing

I'm trying to name a bunch of json filenames which are being parsed from xml files. Each json file includes date information which I want to include in the name of each file, e.g. speech_26_01_2000.json

I tried to use this code:

```
speech_file = 'speech_{}_{}.json'.format(date, speech_idx.replace('.','_'))
```

But the code says that date is undefined.

Normally the code stores date info here:

```
for line in lines:
                txt = line.text.strip()
                if 'Es gilt das gesprochene' in txt:
                    title, date, author = process_init_page(lines)
                    init_pages.append({page['pageid']: (title, date, author)})
                    content[page['pageid']] = {'TITLE': title, 'DATE': date, 'AUTHOR': author, 'DATE': date,
                                               'SECTION': 'reden', 'RECORD_ID': date}
```

And the dumping process:

```
        title_page_info, pages_object = process_file(pdf_file)

        if len(pages_object) > 0:
            print('FOLDER_NAME = {} CREATED...'.format(FOLDER_NAME))
            if not os.path.exists(FOLDER_NAME):
                os.makedirs(FOLDER_NAME)

        resultant = dump_text(pages_object, title_page_info)
        speech_idx = 0
        for result in resultant:
            speech_idx += 1
            speech_file = 'speech_{}_{}.json'.format(date, speech_idx.replace('.','_'))
            #speech_file = 'speech_{}.json'.format(speech_idx) this code works

            with open(FOLDER_NAME + '/' + speech_file, 'a+', encoding='utf8') as f_speech:
                f_speech.write(json.dumps(result, ensure_ascii=False))
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Exception in process file')
        print(str(ex))
    finally:
        print('DONE')
```

As mentioned in the code, speech_{}.json works. But I need the different dates in filename and have no clue how to get there.

Comment: unfortunately there isn't enough in your post to go off of. we can see that you are retrieving the date with `title, date, author = process_init_page(lines)`, however we don't see what `process_init_page()` does. this function should return the 3 variables (`title`, `date`, and `author`), but it is more than likely not since `date` is `undefined`.

Comment: Yes, date is undefined is the message I get.

Comment: The next line above where there is date is ```def process_init_page(page_lines):
    plines = []

    _title = ''
    _date = ''
    _author = ''

    try:
        for p in page_lines:
            plines.append(p.text.strip())

            _title = fetch_title(plines)
            _date = fetch_date(plines)
            _author = fetch_author(plines)
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Exception in process_init_page')
        print(str(ex))
    finally:
        return _title, _date, _author```

Comment: Please show us a full replicable code.